# Convert xml to csv in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

So I have different xml data sources...For example:

src1.txt

```
<foo>
<bar>1</bar>
</foo>
<foo>
<bar>2</bar>
</foo>
```

.. and so on

and another data

src2.txt

```
<aux>
<foobar>1</foobar>
<fushbar>foo</fushbar>
</aux>
```

... and so on

So basicaly different xml (valid formats)

Rather than writing different pig scripts.. is there a way to write 1 script and then convert all these xml data into csv?
Thanks

Comment: what would the csv contain exactly? how would you figure out the fields in the csv?

Comment: @SNeumann csv would be foobar, fushbar\n 1,foo\n .. and so on

Comment: What happened to "aux"? What would you do with more hierarchies? What would you do with attributes? What about the first file? How would you combine the two into a single file? Do you plan to have one output file per input file?

Comment: So, I only want to extract the "elements" of xml. <aux>..</aux> defines start an end of xml... so that is ignored. Just that what is the most logical way to convert any xml file into csv file?? So src1.txt and src2.txt are independent xml files.. I put them just as examples of what i want to do.. I dont combine them.. Sorry for this confusion..

Comment: So what would you do with deeper hierarchies in the XML? Are your xml files flat?

If you want to get one output csv per input xml, I'm not sure that Pig is the right tool for the task.